# Input type=number : Firefox converts floating point number to integer when there are 3 digit after a point

Tags: html, firefox, html-input

On Firefox 34, I getting a weird behaviour on a `<input type="number">`.

When typing something like `11.001` (notice the point) it gets converted to `110001`.

This only happens when there are 3 digits after the point.

Is there a way to prevent that behaviour ?

By the way : I noticed that behaviour on a french Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your browser is using the french locale and french uses comma as decimal separator and **period for thousands**.

From the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input):

> **Localization**
>
> The allowed inputs for certain  types depend on the locale. In some locales, *1,000.00* is a valid number, while in other locales the valid way to enter this number is *1.000,00*.
>
> Firefox uses the following heuristics to determine the locale to validate the user's input (at least for type="number"):
>
> - Try the language specified by a 'lang'/'xml:lang' attribute on the element or any of its parents;
> - Try the language specified by any Content-Language HTTP header or
> - If none specified, use the browser's locale.

If you want to change this behavior use:

```
<input lang="en" type="number">
```